# AlarmManager notification shows previous data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to pass string using alarm manager and receive it in BroadcastReceiver.
But my problem is that I get previous value of string.

```
int min = 65;
    int max = 80;

    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;    
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmAlertBroadcastReciever.class);
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+i1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    alarmIntent.putExtra("value", String.valueOf(i1));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    //check whether the time is earlier than current time. If so, set it to tomorrow. Otherwise, all alarms for earlier time will fire

    if(calendar.compareTo(now) <= 0){
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    PendingIntent mEverydayPendingIntent = pendingIntent;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mEverydayPendingIntent);
```

i1 generates random value.
For example i1 generates 20 then putExtar pass null.
again when service is started then it generates a random value for eg 30
then putExtra passes 20 that was previously generated.